# Run method in separate thread

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, closures

I have a server that have method SendToAll($message). I need separate thread that will be run this method  (SendToAll) every second. I'm using pthreads.

```
class Sender extends Thread
{
    public function __construct($server)
    {
        $this->server = $server;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        for (;;) {
                $this->server->SendForAll("Hello");
                sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I creating object of my server and trying to put it in construct of my Sender.

```
<?php
require_once('includes.php');

runServer();

function runServer()
{
    $server = new WssService("0.0.0.0", 9001);
    $asyncOp = new Sender($server);

    try {
        $asyncOp->start();
        $server->StartServer();
     }catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        runServer();
    }
}
```

But I have an error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Clos
ure' is not allowed' in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin_p\classes\AsyncStorage.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\admin_p\classes\AsyncStorage.php(6): Sender::__construct()
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\admin_p\ss.php(9): Sender->__construct(Object(WssService))
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\admin_p\ss.php(4): runServer()
#3 {main}
  thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin_p\classes\AsyncStorage.php on line 6
```

P.S. Sorry, English -- it's not my native language.

```
class WssService
{
    public $connects_storage = array();
    private $server = null;
    private $logger = null;
    private $writer = null;
    public $loop = null;

    public function __construct($URI, $port)
    {

        $this->connected_users = array();
        $this->loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
        $this->Logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $this->writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\Stream("php://output");
        $this->Logger->addWriter($this->writer);
        $this->server = new WebSocketServer("tcp://" . $URI . ":" . $port, $this->loop, $this->Logger);

        $this->server->on("connect", function (WebSocketTransportInterface $user) {
            $this->Logger->notice((" Connected " . $user->getIp()));
            array_push($this->connects_storage,$user);
        });

        $this->server->on("disconnect", function (WebSocketTransportInterface $user) {
            $this->Logger->notice((" Disconnected " . $user->getIp()));
        });

        $this->server->on("message", function (WebSocketTransportInterface $s_user, WebSocketMessageInterface $message) {
            $s_user->sendString($message);
        });
    }

    public function StartServer(){
        $this->server->bind();
        $this->loop->run();
    }

    public function SendForAll($message){
        foreach($this->connects_storage as $client){
        $client->sendString($message);
        }
    }
}
```

Updated method SendForAll()

```
public function SendForAll($message){
        echo var_export($message,true) .PHP_EOL;
        echo var_dump($this->connects_storage).PHP_EOL;

        if (count($this->connects_storage) > 0) {
            foreach ($this->connects_storage as $client) {
                $client->sendString($message);
            }
        } else echo "There are empty storage";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->server->on("connect", function (WebSocketTransportInterface $user) {
    $this->Logger->notice((" Connected " . $user->getIp()));
    array_push($this->connects_storage,$user);
});

$this->server->on("disconnect", function (WebSocketTransportInterface $user) {
    $this->Logger->notice((" Disconnected " . $user->getIp()));
});

$this->server->on("message", function (WebSocketTransportInterface $s_user, WebSocketMessageInterface $message) {
    $s_user->sendString($message);
});
```

Anonymous functions/closures can not be serialized. You will need to figure out a way to store these differently.

Edit: Took me a while to test this code, (Turns out you cant use pthreads with the latest php). Anyway I was able to solve your problem by doing the following:

Replace the code above with:

```
$this->server->on("connect", new Jeremeamia\SuperClosure\SerializableClosure(function (WebSocketTransportInterface $user) {
    $this->Logger->notice((" Connected " . $user->getIp()));
    array_push($this->connects_storage,$user);
}));

$this->server->on("disconnect", new Jeremeamia\SuperClosure\SerializableClosure(function (WebSocketTransportInterface $user) {
    $this->Logger->notice((" Disconnected " . $user->getIp()));
}));

$this->server->on("message", new Jeremeamia\SuperClosure\SerializableClosure(function (WebSocketTransportInterface $s_user, WebSocketMessageInterface $message) {
    $s_user->sendString($message);
}));
```

Once done you will need to include the correct [library](https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure) and possibly include the correct files (I somehow can never get composer to correctly autoload stuff)

Comment: Now I'm getting 
"
Fatal error: Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin_p\classes\AsyncStorage.php on line 6"

Comment: Where is the class WssService from?

Comment: PHP assigns objects by reference since version... my memory does not even stretch so far.

Comment: @user254948, Look at the head of topic on the WssService

Comment: @Serg give me a few minutes (10-20) to figure some stuff out and ill try to update my answer.

Comment: Updated my post. Took me quiet a while as I did not have a multithreaded php installed and php7 apparently does not allow pthreads (pthreads doesnt support the new Zend API). Hope this work for you (It worked for me).

Answer (score -1):

Your `WssService` object is not serializable. To make it so, make `$URL` and `$port` member variables, move initialization to `init()` method, and implement `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()` methods:

```
class WssService
{
    protected $URI, $port;
    public $connects_storage = array();
    private $server = null;
    private $logger = null;
    private $writer = null;
    public $loop = null;

    public function __construct($URI, $port)
    {
        $this->URI = $URI;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->init();
    }
    protected function init() {
        $this->connected_users = array();
        $this->loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
        $this->Logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $this->writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\Stream("php://output");
        $this->Logger->addWriter($this->writer);
        $this->server = new WebSocketServer("tcp://" . $this->URI . ":" . $this->port, $this->loop, $this->Logger);

        $this->server->on("connect", function (WebSocketTransportInterface $user) {
            $this->Logger->notice((" Connected " . $user->getIp()));
            array_push($this->connects_storage,$user);
        });

        $this->server->on("disconnect", function (WebSocketTransportInterface $user) {
            $this->Logger->notice((" Disconnected " . $user->getIp()));
        });

        $this->server->on("message", function (WebSocketTransportInterface $s_user, WebSocketMessageInterface $message) {
            $s_user->sendString($message);
        });
    }

    public function StartServer(){
        $this->server->bind();
        $this->loop->run();
    }

    public function SendForAll($message){
        foreach($this->connects_storage as $client){
        $client->sendString($message)
        }
    }
    public function __sleep() {
        return array('URI', 'port');
    }
    public function __wakeup() {
        $this->init();
    }
}
```

`__sleep()` tells serializer to serialize only `$URI` and `$port` variables, which is all you need to call `init()` in `__wakeup()` during unserialization.

Comment: You need to be more specific. "It's crashing" is not telling anything.

Comment: Sorry. When WssService started object of Sender run method SendToAll(). When this method is running application crashes without any error-messages.

Comment: It run normally SendForAll() only first time. At the second time it crashing.

Comment: What is the exit status: `echo $?`? How do you know it runs ok first time? Try to log into a file instead of stdout.

Comment: Look at head of topic on the updated SendForAll().
Because in console I get message about empty storage only one time.

Comment: I understand it's not an error if `$this->connects_storage` is empty, that means the number of connected users is zero.

Comment: But if it will be work correctly it will be write in console "There are empty storage" until no connected users.

Comment: Well, with the above code you shouldn't get it at all, as it calls `SendToAll()` instead of `SendForAll()`. You do have `display_errors` on, right?

Comment: Sorry. In my source I already rename method to SendForAll().
Yes, display_errors = on

Comment: I don't think that `WebSocketServer` was writen thread safe. It has no notion of threads.